# Compiling with a parallel compiler for use with Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a (semi) theoretical question.

Is it possible to compile C code with a parallel specific compiler such as OpenMP, CUDA, etc., to write a C extension to the Ruby language that operates better (theoretically) for distributed machines?

Comment: Neither OpenMP nor CUDA is a compiler.  They're both, approximately, extensions to existing languages to implement parallelism in programs.  I think you need to be a lot clearer about what you are asking.

Comment: My mistake, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is, can you compile parallel C code as Ruby extensions, I think you mostly should be able to do so. For example, a numeric extension to Ruby that does matrix multiplications can call into Intel MKL's `DGEMM` routine and MKL is parallelised internally with OpenMP.

You should only be careful not to mix in the same program extensions that use different OpenMP runtimes. Take for example GCC, Intel C/C++ compiler, and Oracle's Solaris Studio. Each of them uses has its own implementation of the OpenMP runtime. These implementations are at large incompatible with each other and mixing them in the same executable (either by static linking or by dynamically loading modules at runtime) is a call to disaster.

Another thing to note is whether the Ruby runtime is thread-safe and whether it could be called from a multithreaded code. This remark is not relevant if one does not call the Ruby runtime from inside OpenMP `parallel` regions.

As there is a single CUDA vendor, one should only be concerned with version mismatches when it comes to CUDA-enabled extensions.

Comment: I believe the MRI implementation of Ruby is not currently thread-safe but I would have to double check, thank you for the informative answer!